# Create pivot table using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a pivot table using vba coding. The row,column fields, filter etc. i am giving through a combobox. The code is not working. Can someone please help me debug it. I am having problem with "month" and "campaign" fields both of which i am trying to use as filter variables. Rest everything is working fine.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "mo_pivotdata!R1C1:R120629C11", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="mo!R107C43", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("mo").Select

    Dim i, j, k, l, m As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
    If Range("cg1").Value = i Then


    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Cells(i, 80        
    End With
    End If
    Next i


     For j = 1 To 10
    If Range("ch1").Value = j Then
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Cells(j, 80).Value)
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1

    End If
    Next j

      For k = 1 To 10
    If Range("cj1").Value = k Then
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields(Cells(k, 81).Value), "Sum Total", xlSum


    End With
    End If
    Next k



    For l = 1 To 10
    If Range("cf1").Value = l Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = Cells(l, 79).Value
   Range("ar104").Value = Cells(l, 79).Value
   End If
   Next l
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum Total")
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    End With





        For m = 1 To 10
    If Range("co1").Value = m Then
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Campaign")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Campaign").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Campaign").CurrentPage = Cells(m, 94).Value
   Range("ar103").Value = Cells(m, 94).Value
   End If
   Next m
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum Total")
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"


    End With
'

   Sheets("mo_pivotdata").Visible = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I get a dialogue box saying

> "Do you want to replace the contents of destination cells?"

I dont want such dialogue box to appear.

Comment: Cells(i, 80).Value)
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1

There was some typo in this line

Comment: You should have posted your error. But thanks for fixing it yourself!

Comment: It has not been fixed yet :(
In the above comment, I just posted part of the code which i missed while posting the code here

Comment: The error is this...I get a dialogue box saying "Do you want to replace the contents of destination cells" .I dont want such dialogue box to appear :/

Comment: Then use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` or clear the sheet first.